# is it possible to make cnc without embedded motion controller over CANopen

Tags: servo, python, cnc, canopen, gcode

I want to make CNC software. while doing this, I do not want to use any motion controller, PLC, FPGA, etc... I use three items. 1-USB to CAN converter, 2-servo motors, and their drivers, 3-a computer. All calculations will be made in software. The user uploads the G-code file and enters the velocity and acceleration of the first motor. Then my software will be calculated the velocity and acceleration of the second motor, third motor, fourth motor, etc. Then I will send the data to drivers over CANopen communication protocol. Then the motors will move concurrently but at different positions and different speeds and different accelerations. My question is that,

Can a computer do all things? Is enough the power of the processor for this job? (the processor for example i7-9750H)
How much precision can it provide?
(I am using Python)

Comment: Hi, Repeating the same question here is classed as "noise" and is not allowed. As explained in the link for [closed question](/help/closed-questions) on your previous question, you should have edited *that* question to improve it, and wait for community votes to re-open it (if the community decided that it was now clear and detailed enough). I'm going to merge the two questions, as they are exact copies. Continue with this topic using the [original question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/580194). Please do *not* ask the same question yet again. Thanks.